# .live() keypress registering twice

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem with keypresses registering the event twice.  I am currently using .live because the HTML elements are dynamically loaded and changing frequently.

I did try using keydown as well as keypress, but the result was no different.  Anyone able to spot what is causing them to register twice?

The Javascript:

```
$(".class3").live('keypress', function (e) {
    if ( e.keyCode == 13 ){
        alert("Enter key pressed");
    }
});
```

The HTML:

```
<dd class="class1 class2">
  <input type="text" class="class2 class3" placeholder="Type Name Here">
</dd>
```

Comment: Same code seems to have registered once here, are you missing anything else to mention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not pasted your code in here correctly. What you are trying to do is this:

```
$(".class2").live('keypress', function (e) {
    if ( e.keyCode == 13 ){
        alert("Enter key pressed");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pnNAM/

The reason this is happening, is because your `keypress` event is bubbling up. So it fires once for the `input`, then again for the `dd`.

If you'll indeed only listen to `keypress` on `$(".class3")`, it'll only fire once.

Comment: Wow, surprisingly that is actually right!  Can't believe I didn't notice that.  Thank you.